# Problem with inferring correct types from generic for arrays

Tags: typescript, generics, type-safety

I have a hard time figuring out how to narrow inferred types in the following example. For now, all format functions accept `string | number | boolean` and expect to return `string | number | boolean`.

Ideally, I would like to narrow these to only 1 type based on value of `typeID`.

```
enum TypeID {
  Number = "__number__",
  String = "__string__",
  Boolean = "__boolean__"
}

type Type<TYPE_ID extends TypeID> = {
  [TypeID.Number]: number;
  [TypeID.String]: string;
  [TypeID.Boolean]: boolean;
}[TYPE_ID];

type Item<
  TYPE_ID extends TypeID,
  TYPE extends Type<TYPE_ID> = Type<TYPE_ID>
> = {
  typeID: TypeID;
  format: (input: TYPE) => TYPE;
};

type Options<TYPE_ID extends TypeID> = Array<Item<TYPE_ID>>;

const someFunc = <TYPE_ID extends TypeID>(options: Options<TYPE_ID>) => {
  return null as any;
};

someFunc([
  {
    typeID: TypeID.Number,
    format: input => input // these should have type "number"
  },
  {
    typeID: TypeID.Boolean,
    format: input => input // these should have type "boolean"
  },
  {
    typeID: TypeID.String,
    format: input => input // these should have type "string"
  }
]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's pretty confusing to have such similar type names (`TYPE` vs `Type` vs `TYPE_ID` vs `TypeID`) so I'm going to make the names distinct in what follows... for generic parameters I use one-or-two capital letters (which is the convention for whatever reason).  Here's `Type`:

```
type Type<T extends TypeID> = {
  [TypeID.Number]: number;
  [TypeID.String]: string;
  [TypeID.Boolean]: boolean;
}[T];
```

And here's `Item`:

```
type Item<T extends TypeID> = {
  typeID: T; // <-- T, not TypeID
  format: (input: Type<T>) => Type<T>;
};
```

Note this is modified further from your example.  You had two type parameters here, but only seemed to use a default value for the second one, so I removed it and used that default value.  But the important modification here is that the `typeID` property is of the *generic* type `T`, not the *concrete* type `TypeID`.  I think you probably meant to do this in your code, but maybe it was hard to see the difference.

---

Now the way I'd go from here is to generate a type called `SomeItem` which is the union of all possible `Item<T>` types.  This concrete type can be used more easily than generic types:

```
type _SomeItem<T extends TypeID> = T extends any ? Item<T> : never;
type SomeItem = _SomeItem<TypeID>;
// type SomeItem = Item<TypeID.Number> | Item<TypeID.String> | Item<TypeID.Boolean>
```

That worked by using a [distributive conditional type](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript#distributive-conditional-types) in the definition of `_SomeItem`, to distribute `Item<T>` across the union of `TypeID` values.

Finally, `someFunc` can be a concrete function:

```
const someFunc = (options: Array<SomeItem>) => {
  return null as any;
};
```

And when you use it, you get the inference you expect:

```
someFunc([
  {
    typeID: TypeID.Number,
    format: input => input // has type number
  },
  {
    typeID: TypeID.Boolean,
    format: input => input // has type boolean
  },
  {
    typeID: TypeID.String,
    format: input => input // has type string
  }
]);
```

Okay, hope that helps.  Good luck!
[Link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/KYOwrgtgBAKgngB2ASQCJQN4FgBQUoBykARsAE5QC8UARAPp3gSlkM0A0u+AygC5kBLEAHMqtBgGd+Q4W054oAIQD2ygDbAAhiDH06xVRu1tcAX1y5eiYLGsAeGFGAAPXqAAmE20jQA+MdgKANrwPqgAdETM5AC6AFxQTCwA3FxQIdZo4XyCIvFQUrnCqcGhKBEq6log+QZV2iWmITElltZQyG4QDk6uHl5lfgFpVmEJMMlQAPRTUHYAtPOw7InKvN7laQBmymQQmrwJABRCCGCHGw6+AJRU-mVXja04ozZ03MoQKF09Lm4gng2Q2ojj+-Sg2jgUAA-B0fjB-AkQMAAG7kEqvKAfL6dYDQajvT7fPEOTKoXwlGZQTHY4n4uEkwYRKIsfwAHwZ3SZ2WkInZnNJYXClSMIF8FhwAGNlCApAUiQAxMAgSViI7KBC8AQyiQJACCZDImjgdlpuIgNzumDSZGAvDAZB04DUaghXkhTwlEkVyslRyCaUC+HwrzQ4zJkRI5HkwagOz2BwSp3OVuT6ypAAtNF5MUlyGlTDHrQoQ2Tw0KRdUi-h4-sLmnUyAzunZlmc+06qKC0Wg8HQ6hy+UeUVq3HdnWk02U5R-A3M9nqe1CjIC7gYtcSkA)

Comment: Thanks for the answer! The trick with distributive conditional types seems to do the job for the arrays. However, it makes it impossible to return some transformed options from `someFunc` (strong typing is lost). Also, I've realized that in my case it would be better to use an object instead of an array for options. I had to add 1 more generic (for the option name - key in the config object). [Here is](https://gist.github.com/elderapo/c022a58576a8288a31235ab3b432b114) link to the gist. Link ot TS playground was too long to fit in the comment.